# jQuery/js works internally but not externally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I paste the following script between `<script></script>` inside the html document it works fine.

However, when I load it through `<script src="example.js></script>` it only partially runs (the first section runs but the second does not).

Here is the code:

```
//SMOOTH SCROLL
  $(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
// End of SMOOTH SCROLL

//NAV ENLARGE
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 1) {
      $('#main-navigation').stop().animate({height: "10vh"},100);
      $("#main-navigation").css("position", "fixed");
      $("#main-navigation").css("top", "0");
      $('#main-navigation').css("width", "100vw");
    }
    else {
      $('#main-navigation').stop().animate({height: "100vh"},100);  
      $("#main-navigation").css("position", "static");
    }
});
//End NAV ENLGAR
```

Comment: Put the onscroll declaration inside the $(function() { scope

Comment: @JazzCat I'm not sure what you mean? Could you please explain? I'm quite new to js/jQuery so please forgive me if this is a basic question.

Comment: Please be more clear what you're trying to achieve. I mean put the $(window).on('scroll', function () {}  inside the $(function() { scope }

Comment: @JazzCat You can view a working demo here http://josiahbertoli.com/josiah-bertoli-portfolio/

Note: the code is internal.

I tried moving the onscroll inside of the function but it still does not work.

Comment: @JazzCat This is the result of the code revision that you suggested 

http://josiahbertoli.com/test/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  //this function gets called on pageload
});
```

The above functions gets called whenever the page is loaded. You wrote your onscroll method outside above function hence it was not getting called. While if you write an code under `<script>` tag in html it will automatically run on page load but the case is not same for js.

```
    //SMOOTH SCROLL
      $(function() {
      $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
    //disable_scroll();
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
    //enable_scroll();
            return false;
          }
        }
      });

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 1) {
      $('#main-navigation').stop().animate({height: "10vh"},100);
      //$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#main-navigation").offset().top}, 2000);
      $("#main-navigation").css("position", "fixed");
      $("#main-navigation").css("top", "0");
      $('#main-navigation').css("width", "100vw");
    }
    else {
      $('#main-navigation').stop().animate({height: "100vh"},100);  
      $("#main-navigation").css("position", "static");
    }
});    

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put jQuery and your external example.js inside ***head***

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/example.js"></script>
</head>
```

> Example.js

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > 1) {
            $('#main-navigation').stop().animate({height: "10vh"},100);
            $("#main-navigation").css("position", "fixed");
            $("#main-navigation").css("top", "0");
            $('#main-navigation').css("width", "100vw");
        }
        else {
            $('#main-navigation').stop().animate({height: "100vh"},100);  
            $("#main-navigation").css("position", "static");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see the edit I made at the end of the original post. There you can see how your code reacts externally. @zakaiter

Comment: You've included the scripts inside paragraphs on the page, which is odd. Put them inside the <head> declaration.

Comment: I have inserted it into the head. Same result.